# Divide image div into pixel rows and attach events

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, google-maps

I have an div which contains an image, which is a vertical colourbar.  This is what I want to do:
When you hover the mouse over any location of the colourbar, a text window trails the mouse indicating the corresponding value of the colourbar.  Here is an image that I quickly made for demonstration purposes:

[image: Mock image]

The way I thought to do this is to divide the image up into rows of pixels, and then attach a `hover` event to each pixel row to which I can then add information.
However, I have no idea how to do this.

Thus, how do I divide an image into a set of pixel rows to add events to them, or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea but it is a bit complex. Now i try to explain it:
you need to overlap to your image, a invisible table.
Your table must have a number of rows like the number of colour variations. In every row you need only one cell.
You can do this table with cycles for.
With css, just assign at all cells the same class so you can manage the hover on all cells.
Tell me if I was not clear

Answer (score 0):

This would require a bit of effort. But to begin with, you can use the html5 canvas property and create the required gradient effect.

Here is a demo I created: http://jsfiddle.net/manublueheart/XSWeK/

And then there is a tutorial on creating the mouse over text for the sections of canvas which you need to impliment to the below code.

See if this helps you.

Tutorial: http://www.elated.com/articles/snazzy-animated-pie-chart-html5-jquery/

Demo: http://www.elated.com/res/File/articles/development/javascript/snazzy-animated-pie-chart-html5-jquery/

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

// Create gradient
var grd=ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,0,800);
grd.addColorStop(1,"blue");
grd.addColorStop(0,"green");

// Fill with gradient
ctx.fillStyle=grd;
ctx.fillRect(10,10,200,600);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a function to translate the y-coord of the mouse pointer to the corresponding color, which I've called getValueForPos(..) here.

```
div.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  var yPos = parseInt(e.y - img.getBoundingClientRect().top);
  var colorValue = getValueForPos(yPos);
  // Do something with colorValue in a hover
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use the mousemove event and get the coord of the mouse pointer then compare that to the the height of the div tag you can calculate it's position. Then have the information you want to display on hover stored in an array that you can reference based on the mouse position over the div. This would give the desired effect without too many dom objects being created.